# How to solve piecewise equation with function of a function

Tags: calculus

I have got the question below for an assignment, I understand how and what the piecewise equation does, but I am wondering if someone can explain what the $f(x)=f(x+2)$ is referring to? Does this mean function of a function?If so, how would I solve this? [*Question*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTH42.png)

Comment: You can write `f(x)=f(x+2)` with \$, like this: \$ f(x)=f(x+2)\$ $\Big(f(x)=f(x+2)\Big)$. See the help or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more information

Answer (score 1):

It means if you know $f(0)$, we know $f(2)$, and we also know $f(4)$. The values are equal.

Similarly for $f(-2)$ and $f(-4)$.

In general, if we know $f(x)$, then we know the values of $f(x+2)$ and $f(x-2)$ and they are equal.

This is a periodic function with period $2$.

Comment: So does that mean that the whole function is a period function, including the piecewise equation?

Comment: the whole function? hmmm... we only have one function isn't it. First draw the part from $-1$ to $1$ and then repeat it.

Comment: so how would I sketch the function between -5 and 5??

Comment: First sketch the function from $(-1, 1], then repeat the patterm on the interval $(1,3]$?

Answer (score 1):

The function is first defined on $[-1,1]$ and then extended to the whole line by adding the condition $f(x+2)=f(x)$ (periodocity of $f$). For example, if $7 \leq x \leq 9$ then $x-8$ lies between  $-1$ and $1$ and $f(x)$ is defined to be $f(x-8x)$. [Note that $f(x+2)=f(x)$ for all $x$ implies that $f(x+2n)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and for any integer $n$].

Comment: I believe your $2$ uses of $x - 8x$ should be just $x - 8$. Also, at the end, the statement $f\left(x + 2n\right) = f\left(x\right)$ is true for any integers $n$, not just positive ones, as Siong Thye Goh's answer indicates.

Comment: @JohnOmielan There was a typo. I meant $x-8$. As far as your second comment is concerned the statement  '$f(x+2n)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and all positive integers $n$ ' is equivalent to '$f(x+2n)=f(x)$ for all $x$ and all integers $n$ '. Perhaps I could have said 'all integers' for ease of understanding

Comment: Thanks for correcting the first instance. However, you still have a second one, as I said earlier, with it being in the statement "... is defined to be $f\left(x - 8x\right)$". As for your suggestion of removing the term "positive", although it's not incorrect, I believe it's more general and it will provide ease of understanding.